# declaration inside function syntax

Tags: c

I am writing in C, not C++ or C#
How can open additional array inside a function and put 0 in all its elements
in one line only?

at the moment i have errors

> Error 1   error C2065: 'new' : undeclared identifier
>
> Error 3   error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'type'
>
> Error 4   error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '['

all errors at the same place - at the declaration of the new array

```
void dup(int a[], int n)
{
    int i;
    int *t = new int[n]; 

    for(i=0; i<=n; i++)
        t[i] = 0;

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        t[a[i]]++;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using `calloc` in `stdlib.h`:

```
int *t = calloc(n, sizeof *t);
if (!t) {
    perror("calloc");
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

new is a keyword specific to C++ and C#, and cannot be used in C.

Memory on the heap in C is primarily allocated via the function `malloc` and freed using the function `free`.

`calloc` is a version of `malloc` that also zeroes the memory before returning.

`calloc` take two arguments, the number of array elements and the size of each array element.

eg.

```
int i = 10;
int* p = calloc(i,sizeof(int));
```

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/calloc/

Comment: No, in C you shouldn't cast the result of `malloc` or `calloc`.

Comment: @KeithThompson Thanks. Never realised you didn't have to cast void pointers.

Answer (score 2):

C doesn't have `new`, only C++.

Use calloc instead, found in `<stdlib.h>`

```
int *t = calloc(n, sizeof(int));
```